# installation of package ‘tidycensus’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, tidycensus, zipcoder

I am not able to use this package. I need it to use zipcodeR package. I have updated R to the latest version. This is the message in my terminal message:

> install.packages("zipcodeR")
> also installing the dependencies ‘fastmap’, ‘cachem’, ‘terra’, ‘blob’, ‘memoise’, ‘plogr’, ‘raster’, ‘tidycensus’, ‘RSQLite’

```
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
tidycensus  1.1.2  1.2.1             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/fastmap_1.1.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 187712 bytes (183 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 183 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/cachem_1.0.6.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 66396 bytes (64 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 64 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/terra_1.5-21.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 94144562 bytes (89.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 89.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/blob_1.2.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 46035 bytes (44 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 44 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/memoise_2.0.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 48283 bytes (47 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 47 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/plogr_0.2.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 13193 bytes (12 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 12 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/raster_3.5-15.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4859396 bytes (4.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.6 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/RSQLite_2.2.12.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4484862 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.2/zipcodeR_0.3.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3705084 bytes (3.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.5 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/fm/01sh249x29n4hjh6c8bww1wc0000gn/T//RtmpGYam0z/downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘tidycensus’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidycensus_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2163672 bytes (2.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘tidycensus’ ...
** package ‘tidycensus’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rgdal’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidycensus’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/tidycensus’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidycensus’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/fm/01sh249x29n4hjh6c8bww1wc0000gn/T/RtmpGYam0z/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Try `install.packages("rgdal")`.  If this succeeds, then try to install tidycensus again.

Comment: That was the issue! I had to brew install gdal in terminal before I could install the package

Comment: @MichaelDewar how do I mark this question as answered?